# how to quickly convert any number to true or false

Tags: javascript

The shortest way to convert any number to true or false depending on 0 and all -1 = false and 1 to rest = true.

How can i do this in javascript. I have tried using if statements, but that looks like long way to do things. How can i quickly log value to true or false for numbers.

Comment: could it be done using shifting bytes using `>>` etc. Or soemthing

Comment: Why would `-1` be false, it should be true !

Comment: Should -2 be true or false?

Comment: no i want it to be false

Comment: To get a boolean if the number is *more than* 0, you do `n > 0` ?

Comment: Get acquainted with JS `truthy/falsey` concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "convert" a number to true/false, where if it's greater than 0 it's true, if it's less than 0 it's false? That's not "conversion". You want a simple boolean test with `>`.

`(number > 0)`

Comment: yes thats what i want...i am asking because in my memory there is something that was like converting number to boolean value automatically does this..or maybe it was a different language.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You want something more "automatic" than `number > 0`?? I really can't tell what you're after here. There is no better way than `>`.

Comment: `>0` save you a character

Comment: ok automatic is not the right word here, something different. It's not that this doesn't work, it's just i feel like i have forgotten it.